# How To Join Tables Inside Join in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I have some tables for my data cafe. The tables are `tb_cafe` for main table, `tb_fasilitas` that has `id_cafe` from `tb_cafe` and `id_fasilitas` from `tb_fasilitascafe`. Then `tb_lokasicafe`, `tb_menucafe`, `tb_gallerycafe`.

I just wanted to get all data from `tb_cafe` and facility name, location, menus, and price.

Is it possible to join `tb_facilitycafe` with `tb_facility` to get name facility by `id_cafe` inside join query for another table? Can you show me how to resolve this.

I use it for an API that results in JSON output.

I tried the code like this:

```
<?php
include_once('koneksi.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_cafe AS tc 
LEFT JOIN  tb_fasilitas_cafe AS tf ON tf.id_cafe=tc.id_cafe
LEFT JOIN tb_gallerycafe AS tg ON tg.id_cafe=tc.id_cafe
LEFT JOIN tb_lokasicafe AS tl ON tl.id_cafe=tc.id_cafe
LEFT JOIN tb_menucafe AS tm ON tm.id_cafe=tc.id_cafe
WHERE state_verifikasi IN (1)";

$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

if($r){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
        array_push($result,array(
            "id_cafe"=>$row['id_cafe'],
            "nama_cafe"=>$row['nama_cafe'],
            "foto_cafe"=>$row['foto_cafe'],
            "alamat_cafe"=>$row['alamat_cafe'],
            "deskripsi_cafe"=>$row['deskripsi_cafe'],
            "no_telepon"=>$row['no_telepon'],
            "jam_operasional_WeekDay"=>$row['jam_operasional_WeekDay'],
            "jam_operasional_WeekEnd"=>$row['jam_operasional_WeekEnd'],
            "nama_fasilitas"=>$row['nama_fasilitas'],
            "foto"=>$row['foto'],
            "latitude"=>$row['longitude'],
            "longitude"=>$row['longitude'],
            "nama_menu"=>$row['nama_menu'],
            "harga_menu"=>$row['harga_menu']
        ));
    }

    echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

    mysqli_close($con);
}

?>
```

I wanted to get a specific result by the `id_cafe`, but the result I have shows more than 1 result for the same `id_cafe`. How can I fix it to be 1 result for one `id_cafe`?

Comment: Is id_cafe unique in tb_cafe?

Comment: yes the id primary key

Comment: But presumably each cafe can have more than one facility (maybe also more than one menu etc too?) If we ignore the other tables and just focus on cafe and facilities, a cafe with three different facilities would return three rows in your query, each with the same id_cafe but different nama_facilitas. If you only want one row, how would you expect three facilities to be represented?

Comment: yeah youre right. I just realize. So, maybe i should make it to diffrent api for the other tables ? example for table facility or table menu

Comment: That really depends on the use case, I don't know much about PHP or web apps so can't say what the best API design would be

Comment: ok,thanks Simon. I hope i can find the best way than